# Rename FileNotFound

Tags: python

I have a directory where the devices that I take care off drop off their backups. The current backup name structure does not provide me with all the information that I need. I get the MAC address and not the name of the box. At the same time the date format is written in a strange format. That is why I made a Python script that should go through all the backup files in the root directory and rename the files. In the attached case the script only has one device - once in action there will be 100+ device backups. The py script and the backups are all located in the same directory.

My Python code looks like this:

```
import os

months={
    "Jan": "01",
    "Feb": "02",
    "Mar": "03",
    "Apr": "04",
    "May": "05",
    "Jun": "06",
    "Jul": "07",
    "Aug": "08",
    "Sep": "09",
    "Oct": "10",
    "Nov": "11",
    "Dec": "12",
}

list = {
    "AAAAAAAAAAAA":"BoxA",
    "BBBBBBBBBBBB":"BoxB",
}

files=os.listdir()

for name in files:
    if name[7:19] in list:
        os.rename(name, (name[27:29] + "/" + months.get(name[24:27]) + "/" + name[20:24] + "_" + list.get(name[7:19]) + name[-4:]))
```

THe directory contents in case of the test look like this:

- rename.py
- backup_AAAAAAAAAAAA_2023Oct23_26393.tar

The conversion does take place and the backup file "gets" converted from 'backup_AAAAAAAAAAAA_2023Oct23_26393.tar' to '23/10/2023_BoxA.tar' . The problem is that the file does not get rewriten and I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\.............\testdic\rename.py", line 27, in <module>
    os.rename(name, (name[27:29] + "/" + months.get(name[24:27]) + "/" + name[20:24] + "_" + list.get(name[7:19]) + name[-4:]))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'backup_AAAAAAAAAAAA_2023Oct23_26393.tar' -> '23/10/2023_BoxA.tar'
```

Could someone help me out with a tip what needs to be added to the code so that the file gets written.

Comment: A file path cannot have `/` characters.

Comment: Well, it _can_, but the things before the last one need to correspond to directories that actually exist. If you haven't created a directory `23`, and another directory `10` within it, then this isn't expected to work -- it's those directories ("folders" in Windows terms) your exception is telling you can't be found.

Comment: (Also, that's a horrible filing system; you want your directory structure to be from least to most specific, so `year/month/day`, not `day/month/year`; as a side effect, YYYY-MM-DD also ensures that your files' alphanumeric sort order lines up with the dates they correspond with, and disambiguates from both the US MM-DD-YYYY and the EU DD-MM-YYYY)